# Почему то header("Refresh:0"); не работает при работе ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Почему то `header("Refresh:0");` не работает при работе ajax

**HTML**

```
<form class="login" method="post" action="login.php">
    Телефон
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    Пароль
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.login button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        data: $('.login').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            notice()
            $('notice').html('<div class="notice">'+data+'</div>');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: А что, по-вашему, должен делать этот заголовок при AJAX запросе?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev мне нужно чтобы если вход успешно то обновлять страницу

Comment: Он и не должен обновлять страницу, javascript'вский `location.reload()` вам в помощь.

Comment: @AlexKrass Я новичок как можно сделать помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обновить страницу AJAX запрос. Этот запрос - это уже не та страница, которую Вы видите. Чтобы обновить страницу в Вашем коде, нужно, чтобы AJAX вернул какое-то значение, по которому JS может однозначно определить, что нужно сделать обновление.

Например, вместо

```
header("Refresh:0");
exit();
```

Формируем вот такой ответ:

```
exit('Reload'); //Reload можно заменить на что угодно
```

и в js проверяем:

```
    success: function(data) {
        if(data === 'Reload') //тот самый Reload, который можно заменить на что угодно
            location.reload(); //перезагружаем страницу через JS
        else {
            notice()
            $('notice').html('<div class="notice">'+data+'</div>');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Обновил. Там просто можно добавить `else`

Comment: Спасибо все работает! А можно попросит у меня был такой да `exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /'>");`  и патом я изменил что то и перестал работать почему вы знаете?

Comment: к сожалению, с этим тегом я работал, только когда просто тестировал его. Думаю, если покопаться, можно найти ответ загуглив `meta http-equiv refresh ajax`

Comment: Спасибо вам за помочь!